# SFML Trying to pass reference of a class as an argument to a function

Tags: c++, function, mingw, sfml

I'm using SFML 2.1 and building with MingW 4.8.1.
When I try to call a specific overload of a function that gets me MousePosition RELATIVE to the window object...

```
sf::RenderWindow* window;
window = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(640, 480, 32), "Render Window");
sf::Vector2i coords = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window)
```

...I get the following errors:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'sf::Mouse::getPosition(sf::RenderWindow*&)'
note: candidates are: 
     static sf::Vector2i sf::Mouse::getPosition()
         candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
     static sf::Vector2i sf::Mouse::getPosition(const sf::Window&)
         no known conversion for argument 1 from 'sf::RenderWindow*' to 'const sf::Window&'
```

The `getPosition()` function:

```
static Vector2i getPosition();
static Vector2i getPosition(const Window& relativeTo);
```

As taken from SFML 2.1 reference:

**`sf::RenderWindow` is derived from `sf::Window`, thus it inherits all its features: events, window management, OpenGL rendering, etc.**

I'm sure `getPosition` accepts `RenderWindow` class objects. For some reason, it's not accepting reference to such object.

What can be done about this?

Comment: You need a reference, but you are passing a pointer.

Comment: I can try to use an instance and it'll probably work. But I want this allocated on heap.

Comment: That is irrelevant. You need to pass a reference to the function. It doesn't matter where the object it refers to is allocated.

Comment: Come on, this is not about SFML, it's about C++ - and even Visual Studio 2013 would have told you that you can't pass a pointer as a reference...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a RenderWindow* to getPosition(), not a RenderWindow.
Try this:

```
sf::Vector2i coords = sf::Mouse::getPosition(*window);
```